# Why is my GPIO High Voltage lower than expected?

Tags: voltage, gpio

I have a GPIO pin tied into 3 LDO enable pins - when HIGH, turns the LDOs on, and when LOW, keeps them off. It's a 3.3v GPIO pin, but I'm reading 0.9v, which isn't enough to turn them on.
Is it because the output current of the GPIO isn't high enough to supply closer to 3.3v to all LDOs?

[image]

Edit: After excellent feedback and guidance from everyone that commented, I started removing regulators until I found the problem one, which actually turned out to be seated poorly, which was causing the unexpected voltage drop. Reflowing the regulator with some flux cleaned things up a bit and got everything working.

Appreciate all your feedback!

Comment: Please provide a schematic of your circuit. Also give the part numbers and links to datasheets for the device whose GPIO pin we are discussing and the LDO's. The short answer is this isn't expected, and something about the circuit is probably not actually what you described. But to know what, we need to get more details.

Comment: Is it possible your GPIO pin is set for open-drain mode?

Comment: Added a schematic that shows parts and how things are connected mostly.

Comment: Is 5V rail up? If not, it will be clamped by LP5907 body diode. Put a resistor in series.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what rail up means, but the LP5907 is receiving the 5v as expected.

Comment: I think I understand. The 5V is up, but the interesting thing is, LOAD+ isn't for the other regulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many thing that might be going on here. I'l let you investigate each of them but here are the main causes I can see.

Output impedance, if you overload a GPIO, the internal resistance of the source will lead to a lower voltage. Essentially, you can see it like a voltage divider where the source voltage is 3.3V, the top resistor would be the impedance of your pin and the bottom resistor is the loading on that pin. I doubt that it is your issue here.

The second is pin configuration. There are many registers to configure an output. For instance, is it open source, open drain, is it push-pull, does it have a pull-up, etc.?  In that case, I'd configure it in push-pull (due to your pull-down resistor). I think this is somewhat likely as an issue. As mentioned, it could be in PWM mode (but if you enabled and configured a PWM without the knowledge of it, you are very unlucky!)

The third issue is that you might have an error in a pin definition/function. Not all IC uses the same nomenclature and you might have inferred that it is an input while it's an output(I once saw a status out that was called shdwn). There's also the risk that one pin is not mapped properly to your footprint or a mistake happened while creating the footprint.

Fourth, I presume this circuit is a mock up of your real. Their might be something hidden (a non obvious current loop) that prevent the voltage to rise properly. These are hard to debug and need the full schematic. Usually, you figure those issues by removing certain sub circuit parts.

To solve your problem, the first step for me would be to try to drive the pin using an external source and measure it's current (cutting the trace between the driver and the inputs). It will tell you a lot! You will see how much current it actually takes to keep this pin to 3.3V. You can also know then if the GPIO of your MCU can reach 3.3V while unloaded. If it does reach 3.3V, by placing a known resistor on it and measuring the drop of voltage, you can figure the source impedance too.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After excellent feedback and guidance from everyone that commented, I started removing regulators until I found the problem one, which actually turned out to be seated poorly, which was causing the unexpected voltage drop.Reflowing the regulator with some flux cleaned things up a bit and got everything working.

Appreciate all your feedback!

Comment: Please do not add such comments as another answer. Instead, edit them into your original question. I took the liberty of doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf), the pin you are using is for PWM. I'm not familiar with this part and I could not (quickly) find how the pins are configured. If set for PWM, it would explain the voltage you're seen. Perhaps you could connect it to an oscilloscope and check:

[image: ESP8266EX Datasheet]